# Bias current and offset voltage, op-amp 741 DC imperfections

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc, bias, dc-offset, offset

Can the effect of the bias current counterbalance the effect of offset voltage?

I am asking this question because today in a lab it occurred to a couple of groups.

Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it's possible, depending on the circuit and your own luck, and for specific operating conditions. I presume you know what input bias current and offset voltage are, so you should be able to figure out whether that is what you observed. Beyond that, your question contains no basis for an answer.

Comment: Write better questions in the future, and provide datasheets and specifics please.

Comment: -1 and closing since you think the rules don't apply to you and you cross-posted this to Engineering.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short to answer your question, you can get an amp with an offset voltage near 0V (and it also depends on how you measure the offset). Its possible with almost any amp. Why does this happen, it really depends on the op amp and how it was designed and manufactured. This is a histogram of the offset voltage for a different amplifier [OPA1622](http://www.ti.com/product/OPA1622/datasheet/specifications.html), but most of them are similar.

The histogram follows a normal distribution and it would be possible in some circuits to have the total offset be zero (because there are other elements like bias current that might give it a positive error and the offset voltage could be negative).

The bad news is, this will never hold over temperature, the offset voltage will drift with temperature. That means if your application requires accuracy, you calibrate the analog signal chain over temperature (or minimize the effects of offset so they don't matter for the application).

[image]

Comment: That's not an answer to the question, which asked if you can use the bias currents to counteract the input offset voltage.